# Javascript dynamic function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dynamic

I have associative arrays within an array that is created and passed as an argument within an object method like so:

```
myObject.method([
    {
        id: "mystring",
        myfun: function(g) {
                   return 'Value: ' + g.value + g.rows[0]['value'];
                   },
        a: "mysecondstring"
    },
        id: "mystring_a",
        myfun: function(g) {
                   return 'Value: ' + g.value + g.rows[0]['value'];
                   },
        a: "mysecondstring_a" 
    }]);
```

I have plenty of instances of this throughout my code and this works fine. The value of `g` is not declared beforehand. Now I want to change the `myfun: function(g)...` at run time, which requires that I declare my associative array before calling `myObject.method()`. Here is what I have tried:

```
myfun: new Function("g", "return 'Value: ' + g.value + " + my_dynamic_variable)
```

no good, then tried:

```
var fn = new Function("g", "return 'Value: ' + g.value + " + my_dynamic_variable)
```

with

```
myfun: fn(g)
```

and this

```
myfun: function(g) { return fn }
```

and this

```
var fn = function(g) { return eval('Value: ' + g.value + my_dynamic_variable) }
```

with

```
myfun: fn
```

Everything I have tried turns up `null` for `g` once the `myfun` code is executed. I'm guessing that variable `g` must be bound within the scope of `myObject`, and that I cannot define it outside of the `myObject scope`, but I am not certain.

Anyone know of a way to do this? Am I missing the mark here? Thanks!

Comment: This definitely looks like an XY problem. What's the real world use case? Maybe you need to think about a different data structure...

Comment: If you assign a function to the key its argument week be evaluated when it's called, e.g., you can reassign it to a new function the same way you assign it the first time. `g` is evaluated when the function is executed, it's a parameter.

Comment: Right, you just need to store that function, and pass a reference to it, `var f = function(g){return 'Value: '+ g.value + g.rows[0].value}`, then `myfun: f`

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? Thanks everyone...geez...the answer seems so simple now you pointed it out... :) @elclanrs - it works! Much appreciated. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store that function in a variable:

```
var f = function(g){return 'Value: '+ g.value + g.rows[0].value}
```

Then pass a reference to it:

```
myfun: f
```